# Formatting choice label of EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a Symfony form that display a list of patients with a checkbox to select each one. I'm trying to format the display of the choice_label sent to the form to make it more readable.

I've tried several PHP functions and HTML tags in the return statement to try and add formatting or even spaces but was unsuccessful.

```
->add('sampleExtractions', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => SampleExtraction::class,
                    'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true,
                    'choices' => $this->sampleExtractionRepository->getDNAExtractions(), 'by_reference' => false,
                    'choice_label'=> function(SampleExtraction $sampleExtraction) {
                            $patientName = $sampleExtraction->getPatientSample()->getPatient()->getLastNameFirst();
                            $patientMRN = $sampleExtraction->getPatientSample()->getPatient()->getMRN();
                            $patientDOB = $sampleExtraction->getPatientSample()->getPatient()->getDateOfBirth();
                          return 'Name: ' . $patientName . 'MRN: ' .  $patientMRN .  $patientDOB->format('Y-m-d');                    }
            ])
```

As you can see I've tried adding details to the return but it all runs together.

I would like to be able to format the output to make it more readable for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create (or update) your form theme, check [How to Work with Form Themes > Fragment Naming for Individual Fields](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#fragment-naming-for-individual-fields). Check also a good example in [Symfony demo application](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/templates/form/fields.html.twig).

Here for example

```
{% block _YOUR_FORM_TYPE_NAME_ sample_extractions_widget %}
{# your custom HTML here #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think this is what I need I just can't seem to figure it out for EntityType checkboxes.

Comment: what do you mean by EntityType checkboxes? About how to do this in HTML?